# Is there any way to create column based on relation between previous column in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

***Given:*** I have **Pandas Dataframe** as shown below

```
| Employee_ID | Manager_ID |
|:-----------:|:----------:|
| E068        | E067       |
| E071        | E067       |
| E229        | E069       |
| E248        | E144       |
| E226        | E223       |
| E236        | E241       |
| E066        | E001       |
| E067        | E001       |
| E144        | E001       |
| E223        | E001       |
| E069        | E066       |
```

***Problem Statement:***

This problem is to identify the **Head of Manager** by using Employee and their Manager data.

***About:***

We have an `Employee ID` and their `Manager ID`. Please note that Manager ID are from `Employee ID`. Since each manager has one Manager above their level.

***STEPS:***

1. First, we'll take all UNIQUE ID in `Manager ID` column.
2. Then for each **ID** from `Manager ID` column, we will look for their respective `Manager ID`(Manager)
3. Then we will create a new column say `Level 1` we will put manager for each `Manager ID` on their respective cell.
4. Similarly, we will repeat the above 3 processes again till there is no `Manager ID` for that particular ID.
5. This way we can identify the `Head of Manager`.

I am able to solve the problem in EXCEL. 
By using `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,$A:$B,2,FALSE),"")`

But this approach lead me to create new column in excel for each level hierarchy. And putting the formula on first cell of that particular column and then dragging the result for each manager

But incase of big companies there would be **n** no. of level of hierarchy. So creating the new column in excel for each level of hierarchy would be time consuming task. Hence, I am looking for an optimal solution.

***Expected Output:***

```
| Employee ID | Manager ID | Level 1 | Level 2 | Head of Manager |
|:-----------:|:----------:|---------|---------|-----------------|
| E068        | E067       | E001    |         | E001            |
| E071        | E067       | E001    |         | E001            |
| E229        | E069       | E066    | E001    | E001            |
| E248        | E144       | E001    |         | E001            |
| E226        | E223       | E001    |         | E001            |
| E236        | E241       |         |         | E241            |
| E066        | E001       |         |         | E001            |
| E067        | E001       |         |         | E001            |
| E144        | E001       |         |         | E001            |
| E223        | E001       |         |         | E001            |
```

> The `Employee ID` column contain **UNIQUE ID** while `Manager ID` contain **DUPLICATES ID**.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: This is a standard `pandas` question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html),The loop is executed while there is no column full of NaN Values. Checking with [`Dataframe.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html), [`Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) and [`Series.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
i=1
df['Level 0']=df['Manager_ID']
while df.notna().any().all():
    df[f'Level {i}']=df[f'Level {i-1}'].map(df.set_index('Employee_ID')['Manager_ID'])
    i+=1

df=df.rename(columns={f'Level {i-1}':'Header of Manager'}).drop('Level 0',axis=1)
df['Header of Manager']=df[f'Level {i-2}'].bfill().ffill()

print(df)
```

**Ouput:**

```
   Employee_ID Manager_ID Level 1 Level 2 Header of Manager
0         E068       E067    E001     NaN              E001
1         E071       E067    E001     NaN              E001
2         E229       E069    E066    E001              E001
3         E248       E144    E001     NaN              E001
4         E226       E223    E001     NaN              E001
5         E236       E241     NaN     NaN              E001
6         E066       E001     NaN     NaN              E001
7         E067       E001     NaN     NaN              E001
8         E144       E001     NaN     NaN              E001
9         E223       E001     NaN     NaN              E001
10        E069       E066    E001     NaN              E001
```

we could simplify it like this:

```
i=1
df['Level 0']=df['Manager_ID']
while df.notna().sum().ne(1).all():
    df[f'Level {i}']=df[f'Level {i-1}'].map(df.set_index('Employee_ID')['Manager_ID'])
    i+=1
df=df.drop('Level 0',axis=1)
df['Header of Manager']=df.loc[:,f'Level {i-1}'].ffill().bfill()
```